# How Do I Build an elementary OS ISO Manually?

Tags: release-juno, iso

I'm installing elementary OS Juno on a new ThinkPad X1 Yoga (4th Gen) with an Intel i7-8665U.

I'm able to boot Ubuntu 18.04.3, but I'm not able to boot the latest elementary OS Juno ISO image. I presumably need the latest HWE kernel and firmware images that are available in the repositories.

How do I build a custom ISO of Juno with updated packages?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a tool called Cubic ([article here](https://www.techrepublic.com/article/how-to-create-a-custom-ubuntu-iso-with-cubic/)) that enabled me to build an ISO based on the current elementary OS Juno ISO.

It can be installed like so:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:cubic-wizard/release
sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 6494C6D6997C215E
sudo apt update
sudo apt install cubic
```

Once installed, start Cubic and it will walk you through taking an existing ISO image, extracting it into a directory, opening a chroot shell inside of it, where you can upgrade packages, and then from there it helps package everything back up into an ISO.

I can now boot into the elementary OS Juno Live CD on my new hardware.